# Tracking sharing on Android

Tags: android

I'm working on an app which has a share button. On click of share i'll show the standard share screen like below,

[image]

I want to know, if it is possible to track if user click on this screen. For example, if user clicks on facebook, i want to know that user selected facebook for sharing.

Comment: You should be using Share Intent to do this, Which is a "View" type of intent. It is showing a Different Activity, which is not part of your application. So you can't track it this way.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know, if it is possible to track if user click on this screen

No, unless you create your own chooser activity.

> For example, if user clicks on facebook, i want to know that user selected facebook for sharing.

That is only possible if you create your own chooser activity, rather than use the system-supplied one. You can create such an activity using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.

Answer (score 0):

From this dialog this is not possible. It is possible to put this sharing into the actionbar with a [ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html).

With [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) this will work on all devices down to Android 2.2. Now you can check wich app was chosen for tracking. Have a look at the [ShareActionProviderSample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ShareActionProviders.java) from Actionbarsherlock